# Double Free Under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC in my application and getting a new crash with this reason :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x17e9a5d0: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

To figure it out , I enabled Zombie Objects , and the reason :

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15d183e0
```

My code :

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(classString);
SEL mySelector =  NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
NSString *arg = @"arg";

NSMethodSignature *sig = [myClass methodSignatureForSelector:mySelector];
NSInvocation * myInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];

[myInvocation setTarget: myClass];
[myInvocation setSelector: mySelector];
[myInvocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:2];

NSString *result = nil;
[myInvocation retainArguments];
[myInvocation invoke];
[myInvocation getReturnValue: &result]; 

NSLog(@" Result String : %@ ",result);
```

What's gone wrong ? Which CFString ??
Thank you for any replies.

**EDIT:**

The object `NSString *result` caused . How to correct this error in the next step?

Comment: Print the address of every object as you create it, and you will know (from the error message) which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` is not being retained when passed back by the invocation.
Try

```
CFStringRef result;
[myInvocation retainArguments];
[myInvocation invoke];
[myInvocation getReturnValue:&result]; 
if (result)
    CFRetain(result);

NSLog(@" Result String : %@ ", (__bridge NSString *)result);
```

Comment: @ngb false. `CFRetain` is totally fine in ARC.

Answer (score 1):

`__unsafe__unretained NSString *result;`
ARC will do nothing with it.